# Using VPN to connect home to work computer gets me work background image

Tags: windows, vpn

I am using OpenVPNManager specifically configured by my employer. It works fine
although I have to reinstall every time there is a Windows update.

Anyway, for the second time now, I find my home computer with the same (compulsory) desktop background image used at work with my employer's logo. I mean, I never downloaded any file or set anything related to my home computer appearance settings.

Is it possible that my home computer is accessible to the IT people from work? And even their mandatory scripts are being run in my home computer?

I have never seen anything like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A VPN takes the computer you are connecting from and puts it in the target network.  So yes, when your VPN is active the IT people from work do have network access to your home desktop.

By being on the target network should not allow them to change any of the settings of your computer (unless you do not have a password).  However, if you are running a program from your employer to connect to this VPN that application has the same access to your computer as you do.

Yes, it is likely your company's automated network policies are either directly or indirectly effecting your personal computer ... and chances are you signed a piece of paper saying that they have that right when you got VPN access.

Comment: Speaking of this, I remember Cisco's VPN client having some functionality to run a program on connection establishment. Could be what's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Windows 10 syncs your settings across devices.
Got it from here:
https://lifehacker.com/how-to-stop-windows-10-from-syncing-themes-between-comp-1789131639